# Ext setLoading(true,true) being called too late?

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a grid with a good amount of data which the user can filter or show/hide groups of columns by using combo boxes. Some of the column switches take a long time to load and I want to call setLoading(true,true) on the grid or the combobox to show the user that the browser is working.

I have a listener function that is called when the user makes a selection on the combo box.  I call combo.setLoading(true,true) before starting any of the code that takes a while to execute. Then I call combo.setLoading(false,false) at the very bottom of the function.

The loading only shows up for a split second after the code between the two setLoading calls has executed. If I take out the call to remove the loading icon, the icon still only shows up after the code is executed.

Anyone have an idea what is happening? This seems very odd to me.

```
categorycomboselect: function(combo, records){
    combo.setLoading(true,true);
    var panel = combo.up('panel');
    console.log(panel);
    var category = records[0].data.name;
    var grid = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('grid')[1];
    Ext.suspendLayouts();
    grid.suspendedLayout=true;
    var columns = grid.columns;//.getView().getGridColumns();
    //slow code that shows/hides columns
    grid.suspendedLayout=false;
    Ext.resumeLayouts(true);
    combo.setLoading(false,false);
},
```

**UPDATE**

Here is my code with Trimboli's suggestion, it still isn't working. I'm showing/hiding the columns based on a string in their ID. I did it this way because the categories I want to show/hide the columns on are dynamic and the columns are dynamic.

```
categorycomboselect: function(combo, records){
    combo.setLoading(true,true);
    setTimeout( function(){
            var panel = combo.up('panel');
            var category = records[0].data.name;
            var grid = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('grid')[1];
            Ext.suspendLayouts();
            grid.suspendedLayout=true;
            var columns = grid.columns;
            if(category=='All grade items'){
                for(var i = 0; i< columns.length; i++){
                        columns[i].setVisible(true);
                }
            }else{
                for(var i = 0; i< columns.length; i++){
                    columns[i].hide();//setVisible(false);
                    if(!(typeof columns[i].itemId ==='undefined')){
                        if((columns[i].itemId).indexOf(category)>=0){
                            columns[i].show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            grid.suspendedLayout=false;
            Ext.resumeLayouts(true);
            combo.setLoading(false,false);
    },1);
},
```

Also, I  wasnt sure if

```
Ext.suspendLayouts();
grid.suspendedLayout=true;
```

do the same thing or not. And if not, which is better.

Comment: It sounds like your `//slow code that shows/hides columns` is doing it asynchronously, so the code you show in your question finishes running while the other code is still showing/hiding columns.

Comment: is there any way around this? I read somewhere something about a callback function I think it was called. Would moving my slow code into a separate function keep this bug from happening?

Comment: **forgiveson** it's right, you see only a few seconds the loading mask because the code that changes the columns starts executing asynchronously, thus it continues it's way down to the end of the routine and removes the loading mask before the operation finishes. You will need to catch the event that fires after the update operation, something like [__columnschanged__](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Table-event-columnschanged) event, but that may vary depending how you are applying the show / hide column solution.

Comment: That is not correct. The code runs synchronously.

Comment: Can you supply an example of the code then? Probably there is something under the hood that you are missing, there are a lot of operations that run asynchronously on Ext that you may be triggering without even getting notice of that. Moreover, there is almost not case on Javascript when you will find a blocking operation taking control of the execution flow totally, otherwise the whole page would be freeze since runs in a single thread.

Comment: @alex9311 Show us the rest of the code (the slow code that shows/hides columns). We can help you more then.

Comment: Thank you for all the information. I applied @EvanTrimboli 's solution but it still isn't working as expected. I posted my full code as requested

Comment: What does "isn't quite working" mean?

Comment: sorry, isn't working at all. The columns will still appear/disappear as required but the loading box doesnt show up. Same issue as before

Comment: Because you're not invoking the timeout correctly. `setTimeout` expects a function reference. You're invoking `busy` and passing the result (`undefined`) to `setTimeout`.

Comment: Okay but even when I structure it like you have below its not showing the loading box.
categorycomboselect: function(combo, records){
                combo.setLoading(true,true);
                setTimeout( function(){
                    /*code from inside busy function shown above*/
                },1);
        },

Answer (score 0):

What you're essentially doing is this:

```
showMask();
for (i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
    // busy loop
}
hideMask();
```

If you show/hide a mask without giving the browser a "break" for it to update the DOM, you won't see anything because it all gets flushed out at the end once you relinquish control back to the browser.

If you wanted to let the mask actually show, you need to give a slight delay before continuing on with your busy loop:

```
showMask();
setTimeout(function() {
    // Busy stuff
    hideMask();
}, 1);
```

Comment: it's an asynchronous call so it will get cancelled right away.

Comment: I don't really get what you're trying to say here. The answer is still relevant, the call in the question is synchronous.